# Get PIC's Intrerrupt Mask Register (IMR) and Disable a special IRQ

Tags: linux, assembly, pic, irq, apic

I'm trying to know, how IRQs map to a special Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT) entry from PIC perspective. The link [here](https://arjunsreedharan.org/post/99370248137/kernel-201-lets-write-a-kernel-with-keyboard) describes how to disable all the IRQs by setting `0xff` as the Interrupt Mask Register by using `0x21` and `0xA1` bus lines.

As I know keyboard generates an IRQ1 interrupt so if I want to disable every IRQ1 from receiving by CPU, I should set the First (Second) bit to 1.

I created the following Linux Kernel Module :

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>  
#include <linux/preempt.h>

int __init hello_start(void)
 {
        asm volatile(
        "in $0x21,%al\n\t"
        "or $0x2, %al\n\t"
        "out %al, $0x21\n\t"
        );

     return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void)
{

}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

After running the above code, it doesn't disable my keyboard. I also set `%al` to `0xff` to disable all of the interrupts but it still won't work.

So I have the following questions :

1. How to disable a special IRQ interrupt(e.g IRQ1 for the keyboard) from PIC (without using Linux predefined functions)?
2. How to know the `offset` that is used in (e.g Linux) to choose the `offset+IRQ Number` entry from IDT?

For the 3rd question, by offset I mean :

> When a key is pressed, the keyboard gives a signal to the PIC along its interrupt line IRQ1. The PIC has an offset value stored during initialization of the PIC. It adds the input line number to this offset to form the Interrupt number. Then the processor looks up a certain data structure called the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT) to give the interrupt handler address corresponding to the interrupt number.

Comment: Which version of Linux are you programming for? Note that Linux likely uses the new APIC, disabling its compatibility mode.  Also, randomly changing the configuration of the APIC without telling the rest of the kernel is a good recipe to hang or crash the system. It might be easier to fiddle around with interrupts from DOS.

Comment: In addition not using the PIC, USB keyboards don't use the keyboard controller that generates IRQ1.